# Could not find the matplotlib data files

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I am new to python and I am trying to create an .exe from py script with pyinstaller but I get this error when trying to run the .exe: Could not find the matplotlib data files.
When i run the script in python idle i dont get this error.

I've tried:

```
 import matplotlib
   setup(
        data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
   )
```

But i get an error saying that setup is not defined.

[image]

Comment: We're mid way through fixing this (see [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5004)). For now please `pip install "matplotlib<3.3"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by downgrading matplotlib to version 3.0.3
Using this command:
python -m pip install matplotlib==3.0.3

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that worked "sustainably" for me is to also downgrade to and earlier version of Matplotlib version 3.1.3. I can now use pyinstaller. I can also run all program without that horrible warnings and stuff that it gives.

I used `pip install matplotlib==3.1.3.` make sure you uninstall all previous matplotlib.

Answer (score 3):

hi i faced the same problem too when generating script using pyinstaller (im using python 3.7). The problem is solved when i installed:

`pip install matplotlib==3.0.3`

Answer (score 1):

Find and edit the hook-matplotlib.py inside of lib/site-packages/pyinstaller/hooks

edit the data section from:
datas = [
(mpl_data_dir, "mpl-data"),
]

to

datas = [
(mpl_data_dir, "matplotlib/mpl-data"),
]

Comment: My freshly installed pyinstaller already has "matplotlib/mpl-data" but I'm still getting an error

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller can't find the location of your mpl-data folder.
Please search for mpl-data directroy and export that in your program

as a workaround

```
import os
os.environ['MATPLOTLIBDATA'] = 'location of mpl-data folder'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this did not fix my problem.

Comment: The `MATPLOTLIBDATA` variable is no longer supported and trying to use it breaks matplotlib. In fact this is partly why it no longer works on PyInstaller.