# Pyinstaller Python and Matplotlib Version causes RuntimeError while processing executable file Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I have processed an exe with pyinstaller 4.0, python 3.8 and Matplotlib version 3.3 in windows 10.
With the console I execute the file.

```
file.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Then the error appears.

```
RuntimeError: Could not find the matplotlib data files.
```

Can you help to solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find the matplotlib data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63103147/could-not-find-the-matplotlib-data-files)

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63103147/could-not-find-the-matplotlib-data-files)

They could go around the problem with downgroading matplotlib for now.

`pip install matplotlib==3.0.3`